# Bad request issue for laravel socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am trying to implement laravel socialite for google. I am using laravel 5.5. Here i am using

```
"laravel/socialite": "^5.3",
```

Also generated credentials from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => '218368033**********',        
    'client_secret' => 'GOCS**********',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/oauth/google/callback',
]
```

In controller I used

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
}
```

Now getting error

```
Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` 
resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": 
"invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required 
parameter: code" }
```

Comment: btw, perhaps you meant to `return` that value from the `redirectToProvider` method?

Comment: Yes......................

Answer (score 0):

Go to vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\GoogleProvider.php

Open GoogleProvider.php and remove the profile from $scopes

```
protected $scopes = [
    'openid',
    'email',
];
```

And Check your code is running now.

Comment: Thanks for feedback but same error